# How edit Ready Ecommerce Plugin templates

Tags: wordpress

I use Ready! Ecommerce Shopping Cart plugin in my website. I would like to know how it is possible to change the templates. I mean the Product List view, Single product View...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Try to search in plugin folder for original default template files:
modules/products/views/tpl/productContent.php - for single product view
modules/products/views/tpl/productCategoryContent.php - for list product view
Also, if you use standard template - see in plugin folder:
templates/standard/products/productContent.php
templates/standard/products/productCategoryContent.php

Regards,
Alexey.